# Windows, Eclipse, Pretty Printers - ImportError: No module named _gdb

Tags: python, c++, eclipse, gdb, pretty-print

**Issue**

I am trying to enable Pretty Printers on Windows to debug STL containers. I installed Eclipse, MinGW (to get gdb-python27 and Pretty Printers) and Python 2.7.7. After configuration, during debugging (from Eclipse and console), I am receiving the error: "ImportError: No module named _gdb".

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 70, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 67, in GdbSetPythonDirectory
  File "c:\mingw\share\gdb/python\gdb\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _gdb
ImportError: No module named _gdb
```

**Question**

I am missing _gdb module. Is this module a part of Python? How should I get this? Did I missed something during configuration? Any direction that will guide me?

**Rescue words - Help Me!**

I tried to find the answer, but I cannot figure out how to solve the issue. I will appreciate if you could help me. Thank you!

**Setup**

- Eclipse: Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers (Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)). I setup path to gdb-python27 and .gdbinit in Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Debug -> GDB
- MinGW: gdb-python.exe (GNU gdb (GDB) 7.5), Pretty Printers
- Python: 2.7.7
- Path: c:\MinGW\bin\
- PYTHONHOME: C:/Program Files (x86)/Python27
- PYTHONPATH: C:/Program Files (x86)/Python27/Lib/
- .gdbinit:

  python
  import sys
  sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/MinGW/share/gcc-4.8.1/python')
  from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
  register_libstdcxx_printers (None)
  end

**Cause**

> MinGW GDB 7.5.1 uses Python Scripts from normal GDB 7.6.

**Solution**

I found the solution here: [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21376381/debugging-stl-containers-using-mingw-issue-with-python-script).

Steps:

1. Download gdb 7.5.1: [GDB 7.5.1](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-7.5.1.tar.gz).
2. Copy syscalls and python directories from gdb-7.5.1\gdb\ to MinGW\share\gdb.

**Thank you**

Thank you fukanchik for your support! Your answer helped me to find the cause and solution. Wish you the best!

Regards,
Simon

Answer (score 1):

**Cause**

> MinGW GDB 7.5.1 uses Python Scripts from normal GDB 7.6.

**Solution**

I found the solution here: [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21376381/debugging-stl-containers-using-mingw-issue-with-python-script).

Steps:

1. Download gdb 7.5.1: [GDB 7.5.1](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-7.5.1.tar.gz).
2. Copy syscalls and python directories from gdb-7.5.1\gdb\ to MinGW\share\gdb.

**Thank you**

Thank you fukanchik for your support! Your answer helped me to find the cause and solution. Wish you the best!

Answer (score -2):

Simple tip that may work for any one have issues with pretty printers:

Replace every '\' inside .gdbinit file to '/' that worked for me!

Comment: Mohammad Shahoud, thank you for updating thread with the tip - it is really valuable for the community. Thank you! :)